# TLS 1.3 record version for application data

Tags: tls

For TLS 1.3, the client hello record version is 0x0303 (TLS 1.2). If the server negotiates to TLS 1.3 (because 1.3 version is in the supported_version), do the application data records use 0x0304 as the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... do the application data records use 0x0304 as the version?

No. The [standard (RFC 8446)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-5.1) is very clear what the version of the record layer should be, and this includes application records:

> ```
>   struct {
>       ContentType type;
>       ProtocolVersion legacy_record_version;
>       uint16 length;
>       opaque fragment[TLSPlaintext.length];
>   } TLSPlaintext
> ```
>
> legacy_record_version:  **MUST be set to 0x0303 for all records**
> generated by a TLS 1.3 implementation other than an initial
> ClientHello (i.e., one not generated after a HelloRetryRequest),
> where it MAY also be 0x0301 for compatibility purposes.

Comment: It seems like 0x0304 is only used in the server hello in the supported_versions field.

Comment: @user2233706: not quite; supported_versions is present (and required for 1.3) in ClientHello _and_ ServerHello (including its HelloRetryRequest variant). But it is not in any subsequent message. The version field at the _beginning_ of ClientHello and ServerHello/HRR _messages_ (not records) is also 0x0303 (without the option for 0x0301 sometimes); see 4.1.2,4.1.3,4.1.4.